# BIML Function support

Tags: sql, automation, biml

GetDatabaseSchema doesn't seem to fetch table valued functions.
Is there another method to extract metadata from functions using BIML?

Comment: Might be useful: https://www.solisyon.de/deriving-metadata-model-sql-server-biml-bimlexpress/

Comment: Avoid using the BIML API to fetch schema information. Besides being incomplete, its slow and extremely buggy.

Comment: @ylax do you have an alternative?

Comment: Yes. Check out Martin JW's schema reader on Github. Very reliable. Https://github.com/martinjw/dbschemareader

Comment: Just curious... did you end up sticking with BIML, or did you go with Martin JW's solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data modeling capability for Biml doesn't have an object for functions so that explains why GetDatabaseSchema doesn't return it. It only exposes Tables and Views and the related properties.

Assuming the source is SQL Server 2012+, you could use the approach I outline in [Biml Query Table Builder](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2017/09/biml-query-table-builder.html) which simply invokes `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` to get the metadata. Except, you'll want to model it against the metadata for your functions. Which you can divine using [What are all the functions and their parameters](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2018/01/what-are-all-functions-and-their.html)

So, you can create Biml Table objects named after your table valued functions with the column definitions intact. For bonus points, I'd tack on the Parameters and types via Annotations.

Comment: This is great. Could you please explain the Annotations part?